# how to transfer file using winscp console from remote windows 8 server to linux server

Tags: linux, windows, scp, winscp

I am currently connected to a windows server. I installed winscp on it. I run the winscp and connect to a linux server. Now on the gui of the winscp, i clicked the console, and use the scp command. the file on the remote server is C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt now i want to transfer it to my linux server. Im planning to automate this using an application like python. but the problem is my code is incorrect. to be honest i dont really get it. so please guide me.

here is what im trying to do.

```
scp C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt remote_server_ip_add@linux_ip_add:/home
```

i dont know if this is correct. it's just not working.

the username of the remoteserver for example is "Remote_server". and the user name of the linux server for example is "linux_Server".

should it be like this?

```
scp C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt remote_server@linux_server:/home
```

i also got this error

```
C: node name or service name not known
```

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: Oh i get. it.. @JimGarrison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is

```
scp local_file remote_login@remote_server:/remote/path
```

And you're swapping terms. In your case, remote is a linux machine. For winscp, windows would be local.

Then, if it will be able to connect to specified server, it will use your certificate to authenticate and, if fails, ask for specified user's password.

Comment: yes i got a permission denied. what should do? should i add a command like the user and password? like scp C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt remote_server@linux_server:user:pass:/home

Comment: What are chances that your user (do you even have `remote_server` user?) have writing permissions on `/home`? I'd say none - never seen so bad access rights configuration before. Shouldn't it be at least `/home/remote_server/`?

Comment: yes. using my laptop , i connected to my remote server then on my remote server i run winscp and connect to linux server.